# Git keeps track of files after adding them to .gitgnore

Tags: git, gitignore

Working on a project on Yii using the PHPStorm IDE I ran into a problem: after adding the configuration file `/prorected/config/db.php` in the `.gitignore` Git system continues to monitor it and proposes to add in a commit. The same situation with the contents of folders `/protected/runtime/*` (with a .log files of app) and `/assets/*`

I'm trying to run following command: `$ git rm --cached protected/config/db.php` - no effect((

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. please, post the output of `git add -v *` in your question. 2. please, learn to use the STO markup, it makes it much easier to read and understend questions.

Comment: doing git rm --cached , does it show you the files now in the untracked section ? If yes did you commit your gitignore file as well ?